# Lineshape lines in Combobox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, graphics, combobox, line

Is it possible to have a `combobox with LineShape` lines in them `instead of text`?
if so how do i achive this?

Its for a drawing application im trying to make which alows the user to select `difrent line types`

(I'm using `VB.Net`)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to inherit from ComboBox and create your own class. Set `DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed` and handle `OnDrawItem`. There are many examples on how to do this. You can use this as start [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem.aspx) or [Placing Images and Strings with a C# Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080719/placing-images-and-strings-with-a-c-sharp-combobox) (in C# but you can easy convert this code to VB.NET)