# Height (size) of a derived Control in .net

Tags: .net, combobox, size

I'm trying to use the ColorSelector class from this example:
 [Placing Images and Strings with a C# Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080719/placing-images-and-strings-with-a-c-sharp-combobox)
I need to step further and use own, external images, thus set the height of the ColorSelector control accoring to the known height of the image to be drawn. So I want to set the "internal" height of the combobox to the maximum of the image height and the natural size of the text. I played a lot with overriding GetPreferredSize, DefaultSize, PreferredSize, MinimumSize, MaximumSize and some combinations of these. (No valuable result so it is meaningless to provide some code.)
How to achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.measureitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hans Passant: Thank you! Somehow I thought that the solution of this problem layed far upper in the inheritance hierarchy, near to Control... Another minor problem: the MeasureItemEventArgs class has no information about the font/text to be using, although the measuring/sizing would need to know the text size as well... Any idea?

Comment: Well, sure you do, you get e.Index.  Just use this.Items[e.Index].ToString() to get the text.